# ¿Por qué las etiquetas script no se pueden cerrar ellas mismas?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

¿Por qué razón los navegadores no reconocen correctamente lo siguiente?:

```
<script src="angular.js"/>
```

En cambio esto si funciona:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
```

Recordé este problema ahora que me acaba de pasar, y me pareció bueno incluirlo aquí. Sin embargo esta pregunta ya tiene respuesta en SO por lo que adjunto el link de referencia:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque el elemento que tratas de usar tiene un `#REQUIRED` como valor inicial en su archivo de definición de documento. ¿Qué quiere decir esto?
En muchos documentos de markup se usa como estándard un archivo .xml que define su estructura.
En el caso de los documentos [html](/questions/tagged/html) se debe de especificar una [etiqueta doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) para evitar que el navegador le asigne una por defecto.

Debido a que dices que usas HXTML si consultas el url que viene del doctype podrás observar lo siguiente:

Una definición de una entidad o etiqueta llamada script

```
<!ENTITY % Script "CDATA">
<!-- script expression -->
```

Una lista de atributos o valores que indican de alguna manera que el contenido no debe estar vacío expresando que siempre debe ser requerido (*required*)

```
<!-- script statements, which may include CDATA sections -->
<!ELEMENT script (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST script
  id          ID             #IMPLIED
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED
  type        %ContentType;  #REQUIRED
  src         %URI;          #IMPLIED
  defer       (defer)        #IMPLIED
  xml:space   (preserve)     #FIXED 'preserve'
  >
```

como puedes ver en la definición oficial que puedes hallar en http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict

si bien la mayoría de navegadores al tener vacío el atributo de `type` asumen que se trata de [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), esto debería de ser suficiente para evitar tener un `<script />`, aunque no para tener un `<script type="text/javascript" />`.

Además como observas en la definición, el elemento script es de tipo *parsed character data* a diferencia de muchos elementos de autocierre como `br` que son elementos *EMPTY* (vacíos). El `PCDATA` además indica que lo que se está sirviendo no es un elemento HTML sino XML, y por lo tanto debe de cumplir con las validaciones.

[Más información en español](http://www.mclibre.org/consultar/xml/lecciones/xml_dtd.html).

Comment: específicamente donde indica que el contenido no debe estar vacío?, solo veo que el elemento 'type' es requerido. Además, igual si no tengo elemento type, en chrome por ejemplo no genera error como si lo hace cuando trato de cerrar la etiqueta (script) en sí misma.

Comment: El que no genere error no quiere decir que no esté incorrecto, debido a la vastedad en el uso de javascript los navegadores tienden a asumir que se trata de javascript, pero bien podría tratarse de vbscript o algún otro lenguaje de scripting

Comment: Para entenderte, no veo que es exactamente lo que impida que pueda cerrar el tag script en si mismo, no croe que el type y lo de PCDATA tengan que ver, si me pudieras aclarar más esto te lo agradecería.

Comment: pues pon tu dtd de manera local, quítale el empty y el pcdata y convéncete ;)